# Whats the proper way to add a new user via a front end form?

Tags: functions, users

I am building a form on the front end that allows the user to add a new user by filling out the name, email, and password fields and hitting submit.

I understand that I can use `wp_insert_user()` with the appropriate user data, but how do I get this function to run when the form is submitted?

I tried calling a function from functions.php onsubmit, but it wasn't working. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a function but might also want to look at Gravity Form's solution for this: https://www.gravityforms.com/add-ons/user-registration/